# how to put data in database with mysql_real_escape_string

Tags: php

i am using a simple guestbookscript and i wanted to secure it with mysql_real_escape_string. But now there is no data anymore put into the database. Before i used this code:

```
$con=mysqli_connect($host,$user,$pass,$dbname);
if (mysqli_connect_errno($con))
{
    echo "<h1>Connectie Database mislukt: " . mysqli_connect_error() ."</h1>";
}

$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];

date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Amsterdam');
$datetime=date("d-m-y \o\m\ H:i:s"); 

$sql="INSERT INTO guestbook(name,email,message,datetime) VALUES('$name','$email','$message',
```

Now i use the real_escape_string in the variable, but no data anymore is put into the database:

```
$name = mysql_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['name']);
$email = mysql_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['email']);
$message = mysql_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['message']);
```

What i am doing wrong?

Comment: You cannot use the `mysql_` version of that. Add an `i`.

Comment: You're mixing `mysql_*` and `mysqli_*` functions. You should use `mysqli_real_escape_string` although I recommend using prepared statements.

Comment: So @Fred-ii- if I add an `i` what do I get?

Comment: @JayBlanchard You need to buy a vowel first Alex. Oops, wrong gameshow Sam.

Comment: @Daan what are departed statements? and why we need it in this case?

Comment: @Testing I don't know what departed statements are. If you meant to ask what prepared statements are then you should probably follow some tutorials.

Comment: @Daan I am sorry for the typo. Yes, I was asking about `prepared statements`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this question shouldn't be left answerless, have decided to post the following:

`mysql_real_escape_string` is a `mysql_` based function which cannot be used in conjunction with `mysqli_`. Those different MySQL APIs do not intermix with each other.

Therefore, you will need to change all instances of `mysql_real_escape_string` to `mysqli_real_escape_string` in your code.

Plus, have a look into using [**`mysqli` with prepared statements**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php), or [**PDO with prepared statements**](http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements), *they're much safer*.